# How can I use Opencv-java to transform the type of img from GRB to GBR

Tags: opencv

How can I use Opencv-java to transform the type of img from GRB to GBR,I haven't find the right methods.

Comment: i doubt, if any of GRB or GBR exist. did you mean BGR / RGB ?

Comment: RGB and BGR are two different type of data in img

Comment: How can I use opencv-java get the values of the channel in a mat

Comment: use split method to split image into its channels, see  [docu](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html); type conversion is done using convertTo method, see [docu](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Mat.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the method and I can use it to finish my job. The codes are :
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, newimage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);